# ssh passwordless login not working on RHEL

Tags: ssh, rhel

After following [this tutorial](http://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/) for setting up SSH pubkey auth, I cannot seem to get passwordless login to work, It always redirects me to the password authentication.

As far as I am aware, I have correctly copied the public key into authorized_keys on the server onto one line and have also removed the trailing "email" address.

I am running a windows machine but am ssh-ing through my git bash terminal.

I have run the command `chmod 700 .ssh; chmod 640 .ssh/authorized_keys` on the server as the user bob

Your help would be highly appreciated. thank you.

The output of `ssh -vvv: bob@myserver` is as follows:

```
$ ssh -vvv bob@myserver
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/bob/.ssh/config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to myserver [192.168.0.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bob/.ssh/identity type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /c/Users/bob/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type 'Proc-Type:'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type 'DEK-Info:'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bob/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bob/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_init: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_init: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 124/256
debug2: bits set: 512/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /c/Users/bob/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 9
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /c/Users/bob/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 8
debug1: Host 'myserver' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/bob/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug2: bits set: 516/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /c/Users/bob/.ssh/identity (0x0)
debug2: key: /c/Users/bob/.ssh/id_rsa (0xa01a478)
debug2: key: /c/Users/bob/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/bob/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/bob/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/bob/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/bob/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/bob/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
    bob@myserver's password: <cursor>
```

**UPDATE:** I have tried to create a key using cygwin this time and it has given me the output as described in the tutorial (with the random key art at the bottom), It has not worked :(

Comment: It appears that your private key is malformed. Did you by any chance do any editing to the key file?

Comment: no editing at all. It _has_ `\n` line feeds

Comment: Is the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file the correct file to modify? if so, how would you restart the ssh server? I've tried `restart ssh` with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After learning from a fellow colleague about `/var/log/*` I took an educated guess that my authentication attempt would be logged in `/var/log/secure`. And so it was:

```
Apr  1 14:31:21 MYSERVER sshd[11980]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/bob
Apr  1 14:34:18 MYSERVER sshd[11987]: Connection closed by 123.123.123.123
```

This error happens because the user directory should only be `rwx` by the user itself, not by group or other.

This is fixed by logging in as `bob`, running the command `chmod 700 /home/bob` and after this, authentication worked with putty via private key!

Comment: This was the issue in my case, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I know nothing about cygwin but this tutorial titled: [3 Steps to Perform SSH Login Without Password Using ssh-keygen & ssh-copy-id](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/).

It's pretty much how I set things up when I do this. I use the `ssh-copy-id` command rather than `cat`, I think its a lot simpler.

```
$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub remote-host
```