# SSh auto login not working

Tags: linux, ssh

I am having trouble getting my passwordless ssh login working.  Below is the log file.

On the client side I have a `~/.ssh/id_rsa` file and a `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

The contents of the `.pub` file are in the `~/ssh/authorized_keys and ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2`

I believe I have the correct permissions too.

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to A.B.C.D [A.B.C.D] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/tommie/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tommie/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tommie/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tommie/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tommie/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tommie/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tommie/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tommie/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug1: Authenticating to A.B.C.D:22 as 'builder'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:Zp2rJ95/sCQ0FcbJsUBs6e7rESRizkMNv1I80b4+FLs
debug1: Host 'A.B.C.D' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/tommie/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/tommie/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
```

Comment: Are you sure you have your `id_rsa` file (and more probably the `.pub` one) ? Because clearly the log says otherwise: *debug1: identity file /Users/tommie/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory*

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122497/ssh-passwordless-login-not-working-on-rhel/122507

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/282319/how-to-use-sshpass

Comment: Looking at the output you posted, you have a key type of "ed25519" and you are connecting to `OpenSSH_5.3`, does your remote version of openssh 5.3 support ed25519 keys?  Official support for ed25519 keys was added to openssh 6.5 IIRC.